# Clustering objects in GPU

Tags: algorithm, webgl

My algorithm is simple for clustering, and it goes like this.

First object is grouped by all other objects which the distance between them is lower the X.
Then we go to the second object, if not included in the first group, we run the same algorithm on the other objects that are not included in the first group,
and so on...

I'm trying to do this algo in the GPU using the fragment shader.
First I set all the locations into a RGBA float texture. Setting for each pixel the location (x,y) - z and w are free for now. Then i draw to a result texture my calculations using the shader. In the end i will read the pixels of the result texture and do my code.

Tried many variations of code, and multi phases draw for performing my algorithm but i'm not happy with the time performances.

The question is,
Is there a way to do one run over the texture to perform my wish (single draw phase) ?

My latest try is this algorithm - My fragment shader

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D locs;
varying vec2 coord;
uniform float clusterDistance;
const float textureSize = 64.;

void main()
{
    // Getting my location
    vec4 currData = texture2D(locs, coord);
    float offsetPix = 1./textureSize/2.;
    vec2 coordIdx = (coord - offsetPix) * textureSize;
    // Getting the index of my location
    float myIdx = coordIdx.y * textureSize + coordIdx.x;
    int clusterIdx = 0;
    float clusterNum = 0.;
    // Running over all the other locations until me and finding the first close object to me
    for (float i=0.;i<textureSize*textureSize;++i)
    {
        clusterNum = i +1.;
        // Which mean that we didn't find any closed object to me so we stop
        if (i == myIdx)
        {
            break;
        } 
        else
        {
            vec2 pntLoc = vec2(mod(i, textureSize), floor(i/textureSize)) / textureSize+offsetPix;
            vec4 pnt = texture2D(locs, pntLoc);
            if (distance(currData.xy, pnt.xy) <= clusterDistance) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the result
    gl_FragColor = vec4(currData.x, currData.y, clusterNum, 1.);
}
```

But the problem here is that the result can cause a chain clustering. For ex. 
if our data is {0,0}, {4,0}, {8,0}, and the max distance to group is 4. Then the first is closed to the second. and then the third is close to the second but not the first. according to my algo, it is returning the index of the second, although that second is out of the picture because is grouped by the first object, and the first is the reference object for distances.

Is it possible to read from the result texture while writing to it?

It would solve my problem, cause then i could check the z value of the result when comparing distances..

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot read and write to a texture in the same pass (with standard WebGL and I think not at all in the way you intend).

Your algorithm seems rather serial in nature, not well suited for GPU/SIMD execution, but I may misinterpret your intent. Remember that the GPU may run a shader program for multiple data-points (fragments/pixels in this case) at once, having no clue about the results of others. 
You also can't break out of a for loop on a SIMD architecture. The for loop will just keep iterating although the changes will not be written for fragments that broke out of it. In other words there is no speed benefit. It's a different story if the break condition evaluates to the same value for all fragments.

You might want to look at other ways of clustering, like k-means.

Comment: Good info about the break from look. didn't know that. For the other issues i knew it. the case is if there is a different algorithm fitting the GPU. About the K-means, I've thought about it, but my clients want to base their clustering according to distance from and not by count of groups. (If i understood K-means correctly)

Comment: K-means does use distance as a basis, but it also requires you to define starting centroids (cluster centers, you could pick a data-point at random). There are other algorithms out there but I must admit I don't know them by heart.

Edit: you might want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set), especially the introduction.